# Find the general solution to the equation $1=2\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

The $x$-intercepts of the equation $1=2\cos(x)$ occur at $-60,-300,60,300$, etc.

How do I find an equation, in general form, that represents these solutions?

Comment: You can write the solution as $\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If you look at the unit circle, $cos(x)>0$ in quadrants $I,IV$ at the values $x=\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{5\pi}{3}$. Generalize from here.

Comment: You can transform your equation into $\cos(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, i.e., $\cos(x)=\cos(\pi/3)$ and then... the solution of @Emilio Novati.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cos(x)=1 \iff$$

$$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}=\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$$

$\iff$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$$

or

$$x=-\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$$

and in degrees

$$x=60+360k$$ or $$x=-60+360k$$

with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Find all solutions to $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Then we can find two solutions $x = \arccos(\frac{1}{2}) = \{\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{5\pi}{3}\}$.

We know that $\cos(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, that is $\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2k\pi)$.

Then $\cos(\frac{\pi}{3} + 2k\pi) = \cos(\frac{5\pi}{3} + 2k\pi) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all k, so each solution to the equation $1 = 2\cos(x)$ has the form $\frac{\pi}{3} + 2k\pi$ or $\frac{5\pi}{3} + 2k\pi$ for some k.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right about that.